# Correct syntax to use in mysql 5.5.25 for not exists

Tags: mysql, powerbuilder, mysql-5.5

Hi I'm trying to write a cursor in powerbuilder 12 to fetch some records . Here this is my query.
I'm trying to fetch some records from the trninvhdr table which are not in the second table.

```
SELECT 
INV_DATE, 
INV_NO,
INV_TYPE,
CUR_CODE,   
EXCH_RATE,   
usd_rate,   
CR_TERM,   
DUE_DATE,   
bl_date, 
TOT_AMT 
FROM trninvhdr
WHERE 
COMP_CODE ='NFL1' AND 
CUST_CODE = 'NLML' AND 
INV_TYPE ='F' AND 
INV_DATE <= '2016-03-25' AND 
NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT * FROM trninvoiceavailability WHERE trninvoiceavailability.COMP_CODE = trninvhdr.COMP_CODE 
 AND trninvoiceavailability.INV_TYPE = trninvhdr.INV_TYPE AND trninvoiceavailability.INV_NO = trninvhdr.INV_NO);
```

Here how I use it in the program.

```
DECLARE lc_retrieve CURSOR FOR

SELECT 
 trninvhdr.INV_DATE, 
 trninvhdr.INV_NO,
 trninvhdr.INV_TYPE,
 trninvhdr.CUR_CODE,   
 trninvhdr.EXCH_RATE,   
 trninvhdr.usd_rate,   
 trninvhdr.CR_TERM,   
 trninvhdr.DUE_DATE,   
 trninvhdr.bl_date, 
 trninvhdr.TOT_AMT 
FROM trninvhdr
WHERE 
COMP_CODE = :as_comp_code AND 
CUST_CODE = :as_cust_code AND 
INV_TYPE ='F' AND 
INV_DATE <= :as_inv_date )AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM trninvoiceavailability
 WHERE trninvoiceavailability.COMP_CODE = trninvhdr.COMP_CODE 
 AND trninvoiceavailability.INV_TYPE = trninvhdr.INV_TYPE AND
 trninvoiceavailability.INV_NO = trninvhdr.INV_NO);

     open lc_retrieve ;
```

The query works fine in the mysql server but in the progra it gives me the following error .

Database c0038 SQLSTATE = 3700 MySQL ODBC 5.2 a Driver mysql id 5.5.25 You have an error in your syntax. check the manual that corresponds to your mysql version for the right syntax to use near NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM trninvoiceavailability.... at line 1.

What is the correct Syntax that I should use to work this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a bracket in this code... where did it come from and where is it's friend?

```
INV_DATE <= :as_inv_date )AND
```

Comment: damn I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out. You saved my day.

Comment: My pleasure. It new it was syntax but it took me a while to see it because it was cuddling that AND.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove ) from your query as per below-

```
INV_DATE <= :as_inv_date )AND
```

sholuld be `INV_DATE <= :as_inv_date AND`